# Symfony2: User Login from Database - Error in security.yml

Tags: php, symfony

I need to log in a user with credentials from the database. However, an error is generated when defining the provider in security.yml.

Here is the error:

```
InvalidConfigurationException: Unrecognized options "class, property" under "security.providers.myapp_entity_admin.users.entity"
```

In the providers section in security.yml I have the following:

```
providers:
    myapp_entity_admin:
        users:
            entity: { class: MyApp\MainBundle\Entity\User, property: username }
```

The question is why Symfony would throw the above error. Official documentation seems to indicate that this is correct.

Thanks,

JB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it looks like I threw in too many parameters. The code in security.yml should look like this:

```
providers:
    myapp_entity_admin:
        entity: { class: MyApp\MainBundle\Entity\User, property: username }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that, because yml files are parsed by indentation, you need to indent "myapp_entity_admin". Right now it's on the same level as "providers" which is not what you want.

Comment: Correct. When posting the code, the editor in Stackoverflow didn't format the indentation properly. Thanks for pointing it out. I'll correct it. Look at the answer below for the solution. Needed to take out the "users:" argument.